# Trying to return all subkeys with a name falling between 0 and 1000

Tags: powershell, registry, get-childitem

I'm working with citrix registry keys in powershell.  Under "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Policies\Citrix" there are numerous keys that are a number followed by a handful of keys that are made of letters, like "Events, Evidence, and IMA."

I'm trying to fill an array with all the subkeys of "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Policies\Citrix" that are numbers, so that I can check values in each of them against an golden image somewhere.

I'm assuming that there will be fewer than 1,000 such keys.  So far, I've tried:

```
$UserSubKeys = get-childitem "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Policies\Citrix" -include [0..999]
```

but that returns nothing.

I can do something like

```
$UserSubKeys = get-childitem | where-object {$_.name -match "0" -or $_.name -match "1"}
```

and do a separate -or for each of "0" through "999" but that seems painful and ridiculous.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Interesting finding as I continue to play with this.

    get-childitem "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432node\Policies\Citrix" | ?{$_.Name -match 1}

Returns the key 1, as expected.  However

    get-childitem "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432node\Policies\Citrix" | ?{$_.Name -match 3}

returns all the subkeys.  Now I'm even more stumped than before.

Answer (score 0):

You could use either of below:

```
# returns all keys whose name consists only of the characters 0-9
get-childitem "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Policies\Citrix" |?{ $_.Name -match '^[0-9]+$' }

# returns all keys whos name can successfully be parsed into an integer
get-childitem "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Policies\Citrix" |?{ [int]::TryParse($_.Name, [ref] $null) }
```

Comment: Thank you for the swift reply. Unfortunately, neither of those are returning anything.

Comment: Are they subKEYS directly under Policies\Citrix, or VALUES you are looking for?  Above will return keys.  And if they aren't directly under Policies\Citrix then I'd need to adjust it.  It would be helpful if you provided a screenshot of Regedit showing what you are trying to pick up.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$UserSubKeys = get-childitem HKLM:\WOW6432Node\Policies\Citrix | where-object {$_.name -match '^\d{1,3}$'}
```

Regex means match where the name string contains only at least one and no more than 3 digits (^ denotes start of string, $ denotes end of string)